# Copy entire row from specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to vba. I have a problem in copying a row from specific cell. That is if my cell position is at D5 then it should copy the entire row from that cell position into a single cell in sheet 2. And i need the count of the total cell copied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more information: which version of Excel you use? The cells in the row are all full or there are blank cells?

Comment: excel 2007 and cells will not be blank. I want to copy till last used cell in that row.

Comment: Please read [ask] then edit your question. When asking about VBA code it's hoped or even expected that the question will include the code that you have developed and tried. It's also good to include details about where the code is falling over and the message received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming activecell as interested cell, to copy all cells on the row you can use:

```
StartCol = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Column
EndCol = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column
mRow = ActiveCell.Row
Set mRange = Range(Cells(mRow, StartCol), Cells(mRow, EndCol))
mRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A20") 'Insert your destination instead of "A20"
```

If you need to insert a specific cell value you can use `Range("your address")` or `Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNuber)` instead of ActiveCell.

You also can use a string variable containig an address into Range, so, for example:

```
mAddress = "D5"
StartCol = Range(mAddress).End(xlToLeft).Column
EndCol = Range(mAddress).End(xlToRight).Column
mRow = Range(mAddress).Row
Set mRange = Range(Cells(mRow, StartCol), Cells(mRow, EndCol))
mRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A20") 'Insert your destination instead of "A20"
```

Changing the value of mAddress you'll have what you need

Edit:
This is to copy from D4 to the end of row

```
mAddress = "D4"
StartCol = Range(mAddress).Column
EndCol = Range(mAddress).End(xlToRight).Column
mRow = Range(mAddress).Row
Set mRange = Range(Cells(mRow, StartCol), Cells(mRow, EndCol))
mRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A20")
```

Comment: Is there anyway to hard-code that Activecell part.??

Comment: What do you mean? you can use a specific address instead of activecell

Comment: Will i able to use specific cell address in that place.

Comment: If i copy i need to copy only from D4 to last used cell. I dont want the values of cells A4, B4, C4.

Comment: It works ..will i able to copy that into single cell ??

Comment: What do you mean? The destination cell is the starting cell to paste all the range

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your initial question you ask about cell count. In order to calculate this, you would just need to use this line:

```
cellCount = endCol - startCol + 1
```